# Update application with libraries based only on x86 architecture

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit, updates

Recently when trying to update my application I came across the message that I cannot do it unless native code **libraries have x64 architecture**. The app has a library that hasn't been updated in years, and despite **it's working perfectly on all devices**, I can't update it on Google Play unless I change the library, **which would result in practically another development from the beginning** because it is the core of the app.
This is a complete disregard for the developer who spent hours and hours developing his Android application.
Is there any way to get around this situation and update my app? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does the library have 64 bit binaries, or is it open source?  If so, you just need to grab the new binaries or compile from source.  If not, then you just learned an important lesson-  never rely on a 3rd party library that you can't control as a core component of your app.  This is a lesson every developer learns eventually, managing dependencies is an important part of software engineering.

Comment: At the time I didn't have much to do. I needed to play a stream in AAC, android did not do this natively. so I found this library.

Comment: I'm not saying it wasn't the right choice at the time-  just that it has a cost, and its something that in software engineering you should avoid or try to mitigate (could the stream have been something other than AAC?  Was there an open source library alternative?  etc).  Anyway, it looks like Android has natively supported AAC for a while, so it may no longer be an issue-  see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats